# How do you keep the state information of the projects you're working on?

Tags: project-management, knowledge-management

Let me clear what is state information of a project:

- Any information that have to remembered or written and then retrieved when one resume its work on a project (for example, on the next morning when arrives at work, or at the evening when start to work on the side project).
- For example, when you open the project/solution how, where and in what form do you keep the information what to do next, the context information of the current task in order to resume the work on it. The project/task management systems are not designed to handle things on this level of detail so I can't use some existing as a base for my projects. I have tried to accommodate a software like FreeMind (mind mapping) or ThinkingRock (Getting Things Done), but it just doesn't work.
- What I need (and I think plenty of conscious developers will be happy about similar system) is something that can be used to hold information in form similar to a logbook. I have read some articles about developer/programmer logbooks and the general idea of the engineer logbook, but since then I'm still failing to implement something that suits my needs.
- The system can be used not only for pure development, but also for more academic projects that involve more R&D although there are commercial projects with even more R&D portion (reading and trying things from multiple books, articles and papers).
- The information about the progress of the project have to recorder somehow in order to look for references, code, reasoning for certain decisions, notes, etc.

Do you know some software that can do the job...or I have to start writing it by myself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/), which is a useful personal wiki.  I use it like a big box of notecards, with crosslinks and hyperlinks between sections.

As several people have mentioned, the toughest part of any of these systems is keeping it up to date.

Answer (score 4):

try Notepad.exe, one log document per project. Or use Word. Or a wiki, Or whatever.

the key is not to find fancy software, the key is the self-discipline to keep the log up to date!

Comment: I prefer using a richer editor, like Word or OpenOffice. That way, it's easier to do things like generate a table of contents and hyperlink the document so you can jump around (and jump to other resources) and export to other formats.

Comment: But, yes, I agree with you on everything else. +1.

Comment: @[Thomas Owens]: thanks - edited for clarity, the text editor is a minor concern ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same requirements and I have moved from a text file to Google Docs. This gives me a couple of advantages:

- I can access it from anywhere
- Simple formatting

I have one file called **todo** and other files for my notes, usually named in a consitent naming convention such as:

- product.name.ideas
- product.name.todo
- product.name.questions

In my **todo** file, I group by date (when I should work on something or finish it) and prefix them with a 3-4 character code to indicate 'who' is is for. For instance:

**. WAITING**
. . PROD1: Review code

**.MONDAY**
. . HOME: Go to bank
. . HOME: Send bills
. . PROD2: Write requirements

**.TUESDAY**
. . PROD2: Review with team

I only plan for one week out, and keep sections such as "Later", "Much Later", "I Wish" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I just use MS Word as a log, and insert links to other files where appropriate. Most of the time, that with a notebook suffice to allow me to pick up a project by reading through the latest entries.

Answer (score 1):

I find a ruled notebook and pen work just fine. I often annotate the margins with icons indicating priority or notes to follow up on later. I think the main thing is to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the project and whether or not the notes are to be shared. I keep my personal notes using pen and paper. Quick and it's easy to add illustrations and references.

Shared notes and FAQ-type tribal knowledge I prefer to use a wiki or development blog for. The blog format is great to provide a timeline and (tagged) references.

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to complete a task, before going home. If I'm not able to do it, a good method to remember is to create a failing test for the next thing you should do.

Bigger things I note on the project-wiki or set TODO-comments in my code (and use tools that find them).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the general consensus so far:  keep it simple and focus on your disciplined use.  I like using a stand-alone HTML file, since it is plain text but allows real links, various lists, and trivial formatting.  This works great for a ToDo list, ReadMe, list of references, ideas, etc.

For an integrated team tool, I prefer a very lightweight wiki.  I am targeting Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/), which is an open-source freeware project that integrates a wiki, source control, and issue tracking--the perfect marriage.

Answer (score 1):

I use [TodoList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx) for keeping track during design and actual development. It's a simple hierarchical todo list, but also offers basic project management features (i.e. setting due dates, priorities and categories and tracking progress for tasks). The files are XML and can be easily processed and versioned, and it includes some basic collaboration feature (though I didn't use that so far).

When collecting a large amount of information, especially if it's primarily some text, tables or images, prior to actual development or when brainstorming or just writing down thoughts, I actually use Microsoft OneNote, though I wouldn't install it just for that. But since it's included in Office, which is installed on all computers at my company, I go use it since I'm quite comfortable with it. I use OneNote only for myself, though, as, well, a note book.

Oh, and then, for information that is not really for a single project, but rather to be re-used, we have a Wiki internally, of course, though it's sometimes hard to convince people to actually use that ("what, wiki? I'll just call you when I need that information!"). Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share the information, a Wiki works really well for this "tribal knowledge" type information you are looking to remember.

If it's just for yourself, then the other answers given here work really well.